# Generalizing isomorphism between a $(1,1)$ tensor and linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

(Throughout $\alpha,\beta$, etc. (Greek letters) denote covectors and $u,v$, etc. denote vectors)

I'm reading Sean Carroll's relativity text, with this being written:

> Although we have defined tensors as linear maps from sets of vectors and tangent vectors to $\mathbb{R}$, there is nothing that forces us to act on a full collection of arguments. Thus, a $(1,1)$ tensor also acts as a map from vectors to vectors:$$T^i_{\ \ j}:V^j\to T^i_{\ \ j}V^j$$

This I understand to mean that we can identify a $(1,1)$ tensor with a map in $Lin(V,V)$ via an isomorphism (also explained here: [Definition of tensor as a map to $\mathbb{R}$ and type (1,1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249863/definition-of-tensor-as-a-map-to-mathbbr-and-type-1-1))

Then I tried to work with a slightly more general example - let $T$ be a $(1,2)$ tensor. And consider this action: $T^i_{\ \ jk}\alpha_i$ - which is a $(0,2)$ tensor. So mirroring Carroll's words, "a $(1,2)$ tensor also acts as a map from covectors to $(0,2)$ tensors". Behind the scenes I consider a map $h$ between $\mathcal{T}^1_{\ 2}$ and $Lin(V^*,\mathcal{T}^0_2)$, where $h(T)(\alpha)(u,v)=T(\alpha,u,v)$. This is clearly linear and I suspect can be shown to be an isomorphism by showing that $h(T)=0\implies T=0$.

With similar reasoning, I can also show that "a $(1,2)$ tensor also acts as a map from vectors to $(1,1)$ tensors". So a $(1,2)$ tensor has a few alternative interpretations: map from vectors to $(1,1)$ tensors, map from covectors to $(0,2)$ tensors, map from $1$ covector and $2$ vectors to a real number.

The problem comes up in this paragraph:

> Similarly, we can act one tensor on (all or part of) another tensor to obtain a third tensor. For example,$$U^i_{\ \ j}=T^{ik}_{\ \ \ \ \ l}\ S^l_{\ \ kj}$$

Whatever approach I described above, how do I unambiguously apply now? I can say "a $(2,1)$ tensor also acts as a map from $(1,2)$ tensors to $(1,1)$ tensors". Again consider a map $h:\mathcal{T}^2_{\ 1}\to Lin(\mathcal{T}^1_{\ 2},\mathcal{T}^1_{\ 1})$, where I have to assign some value like this:
$$h(T)(S)(\alpha,u)=T( \_, \alpha, u)$$ for some $(1,2)$ tensor $S$, where the blank value is filled somehow using $S,\alpha,u$. The only thing I can think of is NOT to use $S$ directly on the RHS. Instead, $S$ as a $(1,2)$ tensor would be isomorphic (I think) to a $Mult(V^*\times V,V^*)$ map $A_S$. So I can define
$$h(T)(S)(\alpha,u)=T(A_S(\alpha, u),\alpha,u)$$

Is the above reasoning correct in explaining the "underlying mathematical machinery/justification" for the second quoted paragraph? (i.e. $U^i_{\ \ j}=T^{ik}_{\ \ \ \ \ l}\ S^l_{\ \ kj}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what the second part (the question) has to do with the first part, so let me know if the following does not answer your question.

Let $V$ be the underlying (finite dimensional) vectorspace and $V^\prime$ be its dual space. I will be using the abstract index notation:

Let $T^{ab} {}_c \in V \otimes V \otimes V ^\prime $ (which is a more verbose notation for $\mathcal{T}^{2}_1$) and $S^d {}_{ef} \in V \otimes V^\prime \otimes V^\prime$

The expression $U^i_j := T^{ik} {}_l  S^l {}_{kj}$ means the
following:

First we apply the [natural isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#General_tensors)
$$ J: (V \otimes V \otimes V ^\prime) \otimes (V \otimes V^\prime \otimes V^\prime) \to V \otimes V \otimes V^\prime \otimes V \otimes V^\prime \otimes V^\prime $$ to $T^{ab} {}_c \otimes S^d {}_{ef}$ the resulting tensor $J(T^{ab} {}_c \otimes S^d {}_{ef})$ is denoted by $T^{ab} {}_c  S^d {}_{ef}$ in the abstract index notation.

Now we apply the following [contractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction#Abstract_formulation) to $T^{ab} {}_c  S^d {}_{ef}$ simultaneously:

- the second slot with the fifth slot
- the third slot with the fourth slot

The map $C$ that applies these two contractions is a linear map (being the composition of two contractions)
$$C: V \otimes V \otimes V^\prime \otimes V \otimes V^\prime \otimes V^\prime 
\to V \otimes V^\prime .$$
We denote $C(T^{ab} {}_c  S^d {}_{ef})$ by $T^{ab} {}_{c} S^c {}_{bf}$ in the abstract index notation.

We can view this whole procedure as a bilinear map
\begin{align} B: (V \otimes V \otimes V^\prime)\times ( V \otimes V^\prime \otimes V^\prime) &\longrightarrow V \otimes V^\prime \\
(T^{ab} {}_c, S^d {}_{ef}) &\longmapsto T^{ab} {}_{c} S^c {}_{bf},
\end{align}
where $B= C \circ J \circ \otimes $, which is bilinear since $\otimes$ is bilinear and $J,C$ are linear.

And since a bilinear map is the same as a linear map of linear maps we receive a linear map
$$
\begin{align}
h: (V \otimes V \otimes V^\prime) &\longrightarrow L (V \otimes V^\prime \otimes V^\prime, V \otimes V^\prime ) \\
T^{ab} {}_c &\longmapsto \big ( S^d {}_{ef} \mapsto T^{ab} {}_{c} S^c {}_{bf} \big)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I'll go through the answer in more detail in a bit. The first part of my question is just to give an idea of the thought process I'm following to explain the first quoted paragraph. For the second quoted paragraph, I'm trying to apply the same kind of thought process to justify what's going on. And as for what I was looking for - either confirmation or refutation of the approach I used. And in case of the latter, where in my approach I went wrong

Comment: I read through it again and have just one doubt - the space you're calling $V\otimes V\otimes V'$ is $\mathcal{T}^2_{\ 1}$, right? Just clarifying since I'm unfamiliar with the notation.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari Yes